# Cannot delete .xcassets content or folder (even in Finder)

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, xcasset

I'm participating in this year's Swift Playground Student Challenge by Apple and encountering an issue in Xcode with the `.xcassets` catalog. I've created some resources and stored them inside resource catalogs (`.xcassets`), but I am unable to move or delete any content from within Xcode **AND** Finder. When trying to delete or move a resource from one folder to another in Xcode, I receive the following error message:
[image: Error message when moving/deleting a resource file from within Xcode]

If I try removing a resource catalog file (still within Xcode), I get this error message:
[image: Deleting a resource file from within Xcode]

My first guess was that the file did not exist in my system, so I right-clicked the resource in my catalog and clicked on "Show in Finder", and (sadly), the file existed and was accessible. So, if I have access to the folder and `Contents.json` file from Finder, I could directly delete them from there, but I got this error message whenever I try to move or delete something inside one of the `.xcassets` folders inside Finder.
[image: Error message within Finder]

(Sorry, my system is set to French, basically, the system can't find my file...)

I'm still new to the whole macOS system and have only developed some small applications in Xcode. But I have never used Swift Playgrounds. Could that be the issue? I remember having difficulties with `.xcassets` files in the past during my university's course on app development on iOS.

There are already some blogs and other posts here about the same problem (well, at least I think it is the same problem), but I couldn't find any solution. It's been two days now I've been fighting with this `.xcassets` catalog, folder, file, call them what you want, and couldn't find anything.

If it can help, here is my project file structure:

```
.
├── GreenLight.swift
├── Models
│   ├── Recordings
│   │   ├── EmotionRecording.swift
│   │   ├── RecordingType.swift
│   │   └── Recordings.swift
│   ├── Soundscape.swift
│   └── User.swift
├── Package.swift
├── README.md
├── Resources
│   ├── Assets.xcassets
│   │   ├── AppIcon.appiconset
│   │   │   └── Contents.json
│   │   ├── Contents.json
│   │   └── PlantStage
│   │       └── Contents.json
│   ├── Themes.xcassets
│   │   ├── Blue
│   │   │   ├── Contents.json
│   │   │   └── New Folder
│   │   │       └── Contents.json
│   │   ├── Contents.json
│   │   └── Green
│   │       └── Contents.json
│   └── ThemesOld.xcassets
│       ├── Action.colorset
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       ├── Blue
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       ├── Contents.json
│       ├── Error.colorset
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       ├── Green
│       │   ├── Action.colorset
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Blue
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Error.colorset
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Highlight.colorset
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Primary.colorset
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Secondary.colorset
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   ├── Success.colorset
│       │   │   └── Contents.json
│       │   └── Warning.colorset
│       │       └── Contents.json
│       ├── Highlight.colorset
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       ├── Primary.colorset
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       ├── Secondary.colorset
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       ├── Success.colorset
│       │   └── Contents.json
│       └── Warning.colorset
│           └── Contents.json
├── Utilities
├── ViewControllers
│   └── MainViewController.swift
├── ViewModels
│   ├── GreenlightView.swift
│   ├── HomePageView.swift
│   ├── LoginView.swift
│   ├── Main.swift
│   ├── Recordings
│   │   ├── Forms
│   │   │   └── EmotionRecordingFormView.swift
│   │   ├── RecordingDetailView.swift
│   │   ├── RecordingEntriesListView.swift
│   │   └── RecordingListView.swift
│   ├── SettingsView.swift
│   └── Soundsapes
│       ├── SoundscapeCustomizationView.swift
│       └── SoundscapeListView.swift
└── Views
    ├── GlobalStatsCard.swift
    └── PlantImageView.swift
```

### What I've done :

Here is what I've done already :

- Close and reopen my project
- Restart Xcode
- Restart my computer
- Try deleting from Finder directly
- Check access authorization on files / folder
- Change access authorization on files / folder

I've created multiple `.xcassets` catalog file for testing, this "bug" happens on everyone of them.

## UPDATE 21/02/24

I've started a new project from scratch. I did not interact with the files in Finder (only from Xcode). I still encounter the same issue.
Could it be a bug with git?

Comment: First of all, don't do _anything_ in the Finder. No. Don't even _look_ inside your project folder, and _certainly_ don't look inside your asset catalog in the Finder. Work _only_ within Xcode. If you work directly in the Finder, you can break your project.

Comment: Second, don't use Folders in an assert catalog. Instead, use names that clump your colors, such as `green-primary`, `green-secondary`, and so on. These are not "real" folders and they can really mess with your head. You can use structs or enums to namespace your colors so that accessing them in code is easy (such as `MyColors.Green.primary`), but don't try to set up that kind of hierarchy in the asset catalog itself.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for those tips! I'll make sure to follow them.

Comment: Having said all of that, I recommend you delete all your asset catalogs and start over, obeying the rules I've just enunciated.

Comment: The thing is, I cannot delete them. I get an error as shown in my question. Xcode can't find the files... Any idea?

Comment: Remember what I said? Work only in the Project Navigator in Xcode. That is where you delete and create asset catalogs.

Comment: If things are so hosed that you can't even do that, then start your entire project over from scratch.

Comment: Yeah I remmener, but even in Xcode I can't delete them... So yeah, it's a start from scratch from me. Thank you very much for your help and your tips (don't worry, I will never work in Finder ever again!)
I'll keep this post updated when I'm able to create a new project to see if the problem persists or not.